# How to detect Emacs Mac Port in Elisp?

Tags: osx, version-compatibilty, emacs-mac-port

I recently explored the [Emacs Mac Port](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/overview) developed by Yamamoto Mitsuharu. It feels great and I would like to try using it instead of vanilla GNU Emacs. However, I have some code in my init files which is incompatible with the Mac Port version. I would like to know how to conditionally disable this code.

I'm essentially looking for something like this:

```
(unless (boundp 'emacs-mac-port-version)
  ;; do this stuff only in vanilla Emacs
)
```

So how can I detect that I am on the Emacs Mac Port from Elisp?

Comment: I think `window-system` will be 'mac instead of 'ns, but I haven't compared to all the different mac versions of emacs yet.

Comment: @amitp You are correct! That seems to work for my purposes. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Or `(boundp 'mac-carbon-version-string)`, its `emacs-version` uses this: https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/src/67b78428be670691c240a20bb7af9248b884d583/lisp/version.el?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#version.el-71, it works for both terminal and GUI.

Comment: @xuchunyang Hmm, interesting. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [amitp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2727/amitp) said in the comments, the `window-system` variable is `'mac` on the Mac Port. Also, as pointed out by [xuchunyang,](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/3889/xuchunyang) `emacs-version` yields special output and `mac-carbon-version-string` is bound.

These things alone should be enough for one to detect whether you're using the Emacs Mac Port, even in a terminal frame.